# How to render PdfContentByte like chunk in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

In case of Chunk we could specify the text and the font which is to be used. For example we can set bold and font size in case of Chunk. While in case of PdfContentByte I am trying to set the text in bold for

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER,"INVOICE",386,596, 0);
```

using

```
cb.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
```

But the text being rendered is too Black, is there any way to render the text as that of Chunk to use a font like

```
 Font contentBoldHead = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial-BoldMT", 14, Font.BOLD);
```

in the PdfContentByte.

Any suggestions would be really helping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to add to what @calum said, the solution is to just use a bold font. `SetTextRenderingMode` creates a faux bold which is why it looks bad to you.

```
cb.SetFontAndSize(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD).BaseFont, 20);
cb.BeginText();
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "INVOICE", 386, 596, 0);
cb.EndText();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's possible (there is a bold-style font corresponding to the one you are using), @Chris 's solution would be preferred.
2. If there is no bold-style font corresponding to the one you are using and you have to use the faux bolding feature which iText provides, you may use `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` method instead of `PdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned` method.

See the sample below:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
Font font = new Font(basefont, 14);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("INVOICE", font);

//you may change the 2nd parameter to adjust the weight of boldness
chunk.SetTextRenderMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE, 0.35f, null); 

phrase.Add(chunk);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, 386, 596, 0);
```

Also check the reference:

http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/adding-text-at-absolute-positions-itext-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(font, size) to set the font to be used in ShowText() and ShowTextAligned()